# Differential equation with cosine squared

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I'm having some trouble solving the differential equation
$$\ \frac{dy}{dx}= \cos^2\left(\frac{\pi y}{2}\right)$$
when $y = 0.5$ its $x=0$ and I need to find the value of x when $y=2.5$, anyone able to help?

Comment: hint: $\cos^2(a)=\dfrac{1}{2}(1+cos(2a))$

Comment: Hint: $$\tan' y=\frac{1}{\cos^2 y}$$

Comment: The hint given by @gammamaster solves the problem instantaneously by separating variables.

Answer (score 1):

Just separate variables.

Remember that $(\tan u)' = \sec^2 u$, so $(\tan (\pi u/2))' = \pi/2 \sec^2 (\pi u/2)$.

Using this, 
$\int \frac{dy}{\cos^2(\pi y/2)} = \int \sec^2(\pi y/2) dy = \frac{2}{\pi} \tan ( \pi y/2)$.

So, you have $\int \frac{dy}{\cos^2(\pi y/2)} = \frac{2}{\pi} \tan ( \pi y/2) = \int dx  + C = x + C$. Now plug in your intial conditions and solve for C.